# How to set few forms horizontal? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with setting a horizontal inputs and buttons in bootstrap, because I have a few forms in one cell table. Like this:

```
<td>

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cart/decrease" >
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartProduct->getProduct()->id}}" name="productId">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini" value="-" name="minus">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
    <input class="span1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16"
           type="text" value="{{$cartProduct->getQuantity()}}" readonly>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cart/increase">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartProduct->getProduct()->id}}" name="productId">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini" value="+" name="plus">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cart/remove">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartProduct->getProduct()->id}}" name="productId">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" value="delete" name="delete">
        </div>
    </form>

</td>
```

Should I take every form in div and set them `float:left`?

Now it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your css:

```
td * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or add a new class to the  you want to be inline like `<td class="inline-form">` with a new css rule:

```
.inline-form * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.inline-form * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="inline-form">

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cart/decrease">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartProduct->getProduct()->id}}" name="productId">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini" value="-" name="minus">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      <input class="span1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" value="{{$cartProduct->getQuantity()}}" readonly>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cart/increase">
      {{ csrf_field() }}

      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartProduct->getProduct()->id}}" name="productId">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini" value="+" name="plus">
      </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/cart/remove">
      {{ csrf_field() }}

      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$cartProduct->getProduct()->id}}" name="productId">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" value="delete" name="delete">
      </div>
    </form>

  </td>
</table>
```